# After Customizing WordPress Display WP not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress website with URL [www.kingsdelight.org](http://www.kingsdelight.org) I just created an index.php which I want to be the homepage of my website. I changed the WordPress index.php fill my Cpanel root folder to index-wp.php so that my php index.php can be displaced as the home page.

Now all the wordpress pages are not loading. What should I do make both my php index.php and wordpress pages to load. I want be using the WordPress to write regular contents.

I have tried loading the site WordPress pages but they are not working.

Comment: What does you new index file have in it? I don't think this is the standard way of editing wordpress pages. I think you're suppose to create a template and have it adjust style that way.